# pamr.cv in R Warning: a class contains only 1 sample

Tags: r, warnings

I want to cross-validate the nearest shurnken centroid classifier in R. But every time I'm running the pamr.cv function it gives a warning that a class contains only 1 sample.
Here is a link to a little part of my file in excel http://gyazo.com/f6aab67674ffbac45d915cbb947c85c1. 
 
I import the file via pamr.from.excel function. here is my code:

`gen.data <- pamr.from.excel("C:\\~data_groep_1-4\\Core_probesets-gene_summary3.txt", 36, sample.labels=TRUE)` 
`mytrain <- pamr.train(gen.data)` 
`mycv <- pamr.cv(mytrain, gen.data)`

So could anyone tell me what this warning is and how to avoid it?